# SQL join to identify group members

Tags: sql, sas, self-join

I have got a client table which pretty much looks like below:

```
    Client List 

    customer no.    Customer name
    123            Kristen Smith
    128            Jeremy Church
    127            Alan Li
    132            Ryan Nelson
```

I need to map it to a Customer_Dim table

```
    Customer_Dim

    customer no.    Customer name   Group no.   Group Name          Cust_Active Flag
    123             Kristen Smith   5491        Zealong Tea Estate  Y
    167             Anna Hathaway   5823        AA Insurance        Y
    146             Simon Joe       5671        Direct Automobile   Y
    148             Henry Wilson    5823        AA Insurance        Y
    195             Graham Brown    5491        Zealong Tea Estate  Y
    172             Daria Smith     5671        Direct Automobile   N
    122             Dyana Smith     5823        AA Insurance        N
    132             Ryan Nelson     5671        Direct Automobile   N
    128             Jeremy Church   5823        AA Insurance        Y
    127             Alan Li         5671        Direct Automobile   Y
```

1. to get their group numbers from below table (which I am able to do by a simple left join)
2. to list all the remaining customers (who are active) from the group numbers of the client customer [I AM UNABLE TO DO THIS 2nd PART] :

Required Results :

```
    Customer No.    Customer name   Group No.       Group Name
    123             Kristen Smith   5491          Zealong Tea Estate
    128             Jeremy Church   5823          AA Insurance
    127             Alan Li         5671          Direct Automobile
    195             Graham Brown    5491          Zealong Tea Estate
    167             Anna Hathaway   5823          AA Insurance
    148             Henry Wilson    5823          AA Insurance
    146             Simon Joe       5671          Direct Automobile
```

Please let me know if any other information is needed.

Sorry, if a similar question has been asked earlier - did several searches but was unable to find anything.

Thanks

Comment: Please post your query what have you tried so far

Comment: Will the customer in the client list ever be inactive ?

Comment: yes, there are quite a few inactive customers in "Client List" as stakeholder has got an outdated list.

Comment: @Richard does that mean we might have to add another where clause in 2nd select statement to not include group no. with 'N' active flag

Comment: If you want an originating inactive client to be in the result set you need to have a condition that allows their custno to be inactive -- queries with criteria for just flag='Y' would eliminate them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

join the tables to get all the group numbers of the clients in the client list and then select from `customer_dim` only the clients of these group numbers who are active:

```
select * from customer_dim
where 
  cust_active_flag = 'Y'
  and 
  groupno in (
    select groupno
    from client_list l inner join customer_dim d
    on d.customerno = l.customerno
  )
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a84514bc0149bd4dbff99fe6fe0a4f09).
Results:

```
> customerno | customername  | groupno | groupname          | cust_active_flag
> ---------: | :------------ | ------: | :----------------- | :---------------
>        123 | Kristen Smith |    5491 | Zealong Tea Estate | Y               
>        167 | Anna Hathaway |    5823 | AA Insurance       | Y               
>        146 | Simon Joe     |    5671 | Direct Automobile  | Y               
>        148 | Henry Wilson  |    5823 | AA Insurance       | Y               
>        195 | Graham Brown  |    5491 | Zealong Tea Estate | Y               
>        128 | Jeremy Church |    5823 | AA Insurance       | Y               
>        127 | Alan Li       |    5671 | Direct Automobile  | Y
```

Comment: thanks, now it makes sense. Doing SQL after a bit long, hence didn't think it could be done this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is pretty simple to get your posted result from `Customer_Dim` table.

if you don't want `Group No.` of ClientList

```
 select * from Customer_Dim 
 where [Cust_Active Flag] = 'Y' 
 and [Group No.] not in (
 select CD.[Group No.] from [Client List] as CL inner join Customer_Dim as CD where CL.[customer no.] = CD.[customer no.] )
```

And

if you only want `Group No.` of ClientList

```
 select * from Customer_Dim 
 where [Cust_Active Flag] = 'Y' 
 and [Group No.] in (
 select CD.[Group No.] from [Client List] as CL inner join Customer_Dim as CD  where CL.[customer no.] = CD.[customer no.] )
```

Comment: My query is based on your posted result, please update your result and input data for same condition.

Comment: Thanks , yep your edited answer does makes sense. 2nd one will work for me. Thanks

Comment: @SachiSinha . . . This makes no sense as the accepted answer.  `Client List` does not have a group number column.

Comment: @SachiSinha: You can makr multiple ans as useful by `up arrow`, but can only mark one answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

for get required results you need a condition in your join

```
SELECT *
 FROM Client            c
 JOIN Customer_Dim      cd       on c.CustomerNo = cd.CustomerNo 
                                and cd.Cust_ActiveFlag ='Y'
```

or

```
SELECT *
 FROM Client            c
 JOIN Customer_Dim      cd       on c.CustomerNo = cd.CustomerNo 
 WHERE cd.Cust_ActiveFlag ='Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

For the case of a client being inactive and wanting to identify the client in the result set you can do a LEFT JOIN with a GROUP BY and leverage Proc SQL automatic remerging in a HAVING clause for selection criteria.

```
data client_list; input 
custno custname:& $30.; datalines;
  123   Kristen Smith
  128   Jeremy Church
  127   Alan Li
  132   Ryan Nelson
  899   Julius Caesar
run;

data customer_dim; input
custno custname:& $30.  groupnum groupname:& $30.    Cust_Active_Flag: $1.; datalines;
  123   Kristen Smith   5491     Zealong Tea Estate  Y
  167   Anna Hathaway   5823     AA Insurance        Y
  146   Simon Joe       5671     Direct Automobile   Y
  148   Henry Wilson    5823     AA Insurance        Y
  195   Graham Brown    5491     Zealong Tea Estate  Y
  172   Daria Smith     5671     Direct Automobile   N
  122   Dyana Smith     5823     AA Insurance        N
  132   Ryan Nelson     5671     Direct Automobile   N
  128   Jeremy Church   5823     AA Insurance        Y
  127   Alan Li         5671     Direct Automobile   Y
  231   Donald Duck     7434     Orange Insurance    Y 
  899   Julius Caesar   4999     Emperors            N
  900   Joshua Norton   4999     Emperors            N
  925   Joaquin Guzman  4999     Emperors            Y
  925   Naruhito        4999     Emperors            Y
  run;

  proc sql;
    create table want(label="Active customers of clients groups") as
    select 
      LIST.custno as client,
      DIM.*
    from 
      customer_dim DIM
    left join
      client_list LIST
    on 
      DIM.custno = LIST.custno
    group by
      groupnum
    having 
      N(LIST.custno) > 0
      and 
      (
        cust_active_flag = 'Y'
        or LIST.custno is not NULL
      )
    order by
      groupnum, custno
    ;
```